# java : Class cast exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a map with strings and tupleList.
i am trying to get the tupleList into double array , but i am getting type cast exception.
my code is --

```
Map<String, TupleList> results = null; -- Some data in it and TupleList has int or double value.
```

public void drawGraph(){

```
    Object[] test = new Object[results.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Entry<String, TupleList> mapEntry : results.entrySet()) {
        test[index] = mapEntry.getValue();
        index++;
    }


       BarChart chart = new BarChart();
        chart.setSampleCount(4);
        String[] values = new String[test.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = (String) test[i];


        }
       //  double[] values = new double[] {32,32,65,65};
         String[] sampleLabels = new String[] {"deny\nstatus", "TCP\nrequest", "UPD\nrequest", "ICMP\nrequest"};
         String[] barLabels = new String[] {"STATUS", "TCP", "UDP", "PING"};

         //chart.setSampleValues(0, values);
         chart.setSampleColor(0, new Color(0xFFA000));
         chart.setRange(0, 88);
         chart.setFont("rangeLabelFont", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13));
```

error----

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: somePackagename.datamodel.TupleList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.ibm.biginsights.ExampleAPI.drawGraph(ExampleAPI.java:177)
at com.ibm.biginsights.ExampleAPI.main(ExampleAPI.java:95)
```

i am getting exception @

```
  String[] values = new String[test.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = (String) test[i];
```

Thanks

Comment: i have some integer values in my map value. When i am trying to get them in string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the error is taking place here: `values[i] = (String) test[i];`. The problem is that you are trying to throw an object of type `TupleList` into a string. What you need to do, is to call the `.toString()` method, that should give you a string representation of the object.

Note however, you will have to override the `toString()` method within the `TupleList` class so that you can get a string representation of the object which suits your needs.

So in short, just doing `test[i].toString()` will most likely yield something along the lines of this: `TupleList@122545`. What you need to do is this:

```
public class TupleList
...

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "...";
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your test array contains TupleLists. You add them at

```
    Object[] test = new Object[results.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Entry<String, TupleList> mapEntry : results.entrySet()) {
        test[index] = mapEntry.getValue();
        index++;
    }
```

And then you cast TupleList to String ang get ClassCastException
You could use toString if you want.

```
values[i] = test[i].toString();
```